# Design help: Hashmap in testng dataprovider

Tags: design-patterns, testng

I been writing Test scripts using TestNG's DataProvider feature. Till now I was happy with the way I was doing it as the number of parameters I was passing was less than 10, but some of the new pages I am testing have more than 30-35 parameters, adding these parameters to the Test Method makes it look really ugly so I started using the varArgs 'Object...'.

Its a good way of dynamically passing parameters, but then using them is difficult as you have to be really careful with the indexes and prone to errors if this has to be done for a lot of methods.

I tried passing the test data as a ArrayList>, where the HashMap is the Column Name-Value pair but TestNG wont accept this as HashMap cant be cast as Object[]. The reason I thought of using HashMap is because you can query a key and get its value and the key is known to me. I could have written a common method to get the value and assign it to the variable representing the names of the fields on the page.

The Data Source (XLS) only stores the test data that is entered on the page, so its purely data-driven and not keyword based. All the pages I am testing are data entry pages.

What is the best way to have some kind of identity on the test data and also get TestNG to accept it.

Any help in this regards is really appreciated.

Thank you,
John

Answer (score 2):

Why not use a Map as argument to your test method and hav your dataprovider return an argument array only consisting of the map for each data set:

```
public class MyTest {

  @Test(...)
  public void testThis(Map<String,Object> args) {
    String arg1 = (String) args1.get("args1");
    ...
  }

  @Dataprovider(...)
  public Object[][] dataprovider() {
    return new Object[][]{
      { map("arg1", "foo") },
      { map("arg1", "bar", "arg2", new Object() }
    };
  }

  private Map<String,Object> map(Object... kv) {
    //helper that creates Map from Array for brevity.
  }

}
```

This should ease the use of variable arguments by emulating other languages named parameter passing.

Answer (score 1):

Why not write your own conversion function that turns a Map into an Object[], which you can then pass to the TestNG method?

Comment: Thanks Cedric for taking time out of your busy schedule, if I convert it then I will lose the functionality of HashMap & probably end up doing a lot of unchecked cast. Other way I was thinking of was returning the data as ArrayList<ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>> where the inner arraylist will be of size 1. That way it may allow me to cast it as an Object[]. I am a little tied up at the moment but I will try this later.